# PHP - Build a SQL query with multiple checkbox choices

Tags: php, sql

I build a `SQL` query using a form and `POST` method. I'm using checkboxes and I can have several values, so I want to insert a `OR` when I have mutiple choices.

```
# Form
<form action="" method="post">
    <input id="01" name="choice[]" type="checkbox" value="01">
    <input id="02" name="choice[]" type="checkbox" value="02">
    <input id="03" name="choice[]" type="checkbox" value="03">
    <input type="submit"  name="btSubmit"/>
</form>

# Query
if(isset($_POST["btSubmit"]) and !empty($_POST['choice'])) {

    foreach($_POST["choice"] as $value_choice) echo  "type = '$value_choice' OR ";

    $sql = $db->query("SELECT name, type
                   FROM data.myData 
                   WHERE '$value_choice'
                   GROUP BY name, type
                   ORDER BY name, type");

}
```

When I have several choices this syntax is wrong because because of the last `OR` my query looks like this :

```
SELECT name, type FROM data.myData
WHERE type='01' OR type='02' OR type='03' OR
GROUP BY name, type
ORDER BY name, type
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I would also like to point out that I think (so far) most answers are open to SQL injection issues.  Although it is assumed that only valid values can be passed, it's not too difficult to invent your own for malicious purposes.

Comment: @GeoGyro hi, i've just noticed -Himanshu Upadhyay-  answered your question before i did one minute or something so please feel free to accept his answer instead of mine.

Comment: @AmrAly, thank you so much for promoting my answer.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay You're welcome ;)

Comment: @NigelRen How do you prevent this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a comma separated string with all checkbox values like this:

```
$all_ck_box = implode(',', $_POST['choice']);
```

And then use it with `where in` clause of mysql query.

```
SELECT name, type FROM data.myData
 WHERE type IN ($all_ck_box)
 GROUP BY name, type
```

So your updated code would be :

```
if(isset($_POST["btSubmit"]) and !empty($_POST['choice'])) {

    $all_ck_box = implode(',', $_POST['choice']);
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT name, type
               FROM data.myData 
               WHERE type IN (".$all_ck_box.")
               GROUP BY name, type
               ORDER BY name, type");
}
```

Comment: It's a good way but some quotes are missing. `$all_ck_box` is like `01,02,03`, for `SQL` it must be `'01','02','03'`

Comment: To respect `SQL` quotes `$all_ck_box = "'" . implode("','", $_POST['choice']) . "'";`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `OR` operator you can use `IN`

like:

```
 SELECT name, type FROM data.myData
 WHERE type IN ('01','02','03')
 GROUP BY name, type
```

Comment: it will throw error if none of the option is selected and it's not handled in condition

Comment: You can write a checking condition for that only! hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Change your `foreach` as follow :

```
foreach($_POST["choice"] as $value_choice) {
    if ($value_choice === end($_POST["choice"]))
    {
        echo  "type = '$value_choice'";
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "type = '$value_choice' OR ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rahul Mukherjee suggested you can do something like this:

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT name, type
               FROM data.myData 
               WHERE type IN (".
               implode(',', $_POST["choice"])
               .") GROUP BY name, type
               ORDER BY name, type");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you:

```
$orClause = "";
$or = "";
foreach($_POST["choice"] as $value_choice) {
    $orClause .= $or . " type = '$value_choice' ";
    $or = " OR ";
}

$sql = $db->query("SELECT name, type
                   FROM data.myData 
                   WHERE $orClause
                   GROUP BY name, type
                   ORDER BY name, type");
```

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.